# Show $Z_n=(-1)^n\cos {\pi Y_n}$ is a martingale, $Y_n$ symmetric walk

Tags: probability, martingales

Show that the stochastic process $$Z_n := (−1)^n \cos(πY_n)$$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F_n}\}_{n\geq0}$,$\mathcal{F_n}\ =\sigma(X_1,\dots X_n)$ where $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a symmetric random walk.

So I need to show $E(Z_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=Z_{n-1}$. A symmetric walk is a martingale so $E(Y_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})=Y_{n-1}$.

I have tried to use properties of expectation, the addition formula for cosine and a telescope sum but I haven't gotten anywhere. Can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: What are $X_i$ exactly? Are they just equally likely to be $\pm 1$ with some additional probability to be $0$, or are they arbitrary mean zero variables?

Comment: First one, $P(X_i=-1)=P(X_i=1)=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X_i$ are $\pm k$, where $k$ is an odd integer, then:

$$E(Z_n|F_{n-1})= E[(-1)^n\cos(\pi Y_{n-1}+\pi X_n)|F_{n-1}).$$

Now use law of angle addition to get $\cos(Y_{n-1}+X_n)=\cos(\pi Y_{n-1})(-1)-0 = -\cos(\pi Y_{n-1}).$

So $E(Z_n|F_{n-1}) = E[Z_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]=Z_{n-1}.$

Comment: True, but are we all aware that we speak about a constant process then ? No conditional expectation needed. Weird.

Comment: @Olivier: I meant more generally $P(X=\pm k)=1/2$ where $k$ is odd.

Comment: I got it. But even in this case, $Z_n$ is constant ! (You could take whatever random variables distributed on the odd integers for your increments, to the same effect).